# Is there a way to get to the beginning of a command without holding the arrow?

Tags: unix, command-line, terminal

I've been using unix for some time, and I would like to know if there is a simple command for getting to the begginging of a command without holding the arrow.

Say I want to change /usr/ to /foo/

```
/usr/bin/apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs bindings: `Ctrl+A` or `Home`

VIM bindings: `0`

Answer (score 3):

After you typed the first command you could use

```
$^/usr/^/foo/
```

To run the last command by replacing `/usr/` with `/foo/`

#### Example

```
$ echo "/foo/bar/"
/foo/bar/
$ ^/foo/^/baz/
echo "/baz/bar/"
/baz/bar/
```